# Extend TextBox's UseSystemPasswordChar security

Tags: c#, winforms, security, textbox, password-protection

While working on a remember me feature (for both username and password credentials) I noticed that it was possible to recover the passwords that were hidden when setting UseSystemPasswordChar property to true. Example on the screenshot below:

[image: UseSystemPasswordChar property set to true]

I also noticed that although a lot of applications suffer for the same issue not all do, so I assume there must be a way to avoid this.

The question is, what approach do I need to take to ensure it is not possible to retrieve the credentials using this method ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you worried about another app injecting itself into your memory space and query the object/control?  Every control will contain the password in memory - to allow it's subsequent handoff to whatever needs it.

Comment: There must be different method though since if you read the discussion I had with Scott you will see me mentioning KeyPass which is also written in C# without suffering from this. I'm trying to find a few more examples, though it's tricky finding C# applications that require login credentials. A few more examples: filezilla suffers for this | Minecraft's launcher doesn't. Both different languages though. The only .NET application I managed to find so far that doesn't expose the login info is KeyPass. But since even one application is able to do this then it must be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Once the password has been saved you do not put the old password back in to the box when you show it to the user again. You put some placeholder text that if the textbox matches the placeholder text you use the stored password.

As for some other tips, if possible store the hash of the password instead of the password itself in memory. You can use the strings utility from something like Process Explorer to find the password string in memory.

If it is not possible to store the hash instead of the password (for example if you are connecting to some other service and it requires the plaintext password to be submitted) you can use a [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) and that will keep the in-memory string encrypted.

As for storing the password safely for long term, not just in memory, use the [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata) class to encrypt the string before you write it to the hard drive and set the [DataProtectionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotectionscope) to `CurrentUser` so only the logged in user can get the data.

Just keep in mind: You can't make it impossible for someone to find what the stored password is, but you can significantly raise the bar on the difficulty in getting it.

Comment: That was my first approach as well (using placeholder characters with the same length as the actual password), but since the programs that don't suffer for this display no text what so ever I assume there must be another way. An example for that would be  KeePass application which is written in C# as well. You cannot retrieve the characters that are used for it's login screen even if you actually type them yourself before trying.

Comment: It does not need to be the same length, Windows does this all the time, go count the number of dots on a saved password for service that logs in as a user or a scheduled task some time. As for how keypass does it, I don't know, I was under the impression that enabling the password mask set some bits under the hood that prevented other apps from seeing too. They could be using a non standard control like [SecureTextBox](http://securetextbox.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That was my guess/hope as well till I stumbled on this. What I'm looking at the moment is to find out how other programs accomplish this since they are C# applications like the one I mention above that don't have this issue.